# Simulating falling and moving wooden house?

Tags: simulation, matlab, building-physics

In Sweden, a newly constructed 150 m2 wooden residence built atop a mud foundation has exhibited significant structural instability. Over a period of 500 days, the house has settled by 90 millimeters and shifted laterally by 120 millimeters. Notably, an 800-millimeter clearance beneath the house facilitates crawl space access, where water intrusion is evident. This water presence is believed to have altered the mud's consistency to a slimier form, consequently undermining lateral support to the foundation due to the absence of horizontal piling—a crucial construction oversight.

Further examination reveals additional construction deficiencies. Unfilled gaps in the cavity plates represent a significant error, potentially exacerbated by the absence of freezing protection panels on one side of the house. This omission likely contributes to the observed sideways movement. The structural integrity of the foundation is further called into question by evident damages: a positive result on the gold ball test indicates unevenness or sloping floors, with depressions measuring up to 10 millimeters and comparable gaps at doorsteps and ceilings.

These findings suggest both vertical settlement and horizontal displacement of the foundation, as corroborated by official city measurements. The precarious positioning of the cavity plates poses an immediate risk, as their dislodgment could precipitate the collapse of flooring systems above.

The culmination of these issues—ranging from the lack of foundational support and water-induced soil degradation to construction errors—underscores the urgent need for remedial actions. These actions should aim not only to stabilize and rectify the current state of the residence but also to prevent further degradation and ensure the safety of its occupants. However, many experts already think to break the house would be the best solution because the repairs will be very expensive.

BUT now, I have to present the case to amateurs so I am thinking to visualise the falling and moving house. Maybe separately the foundation and the house.

Can you propose some simulation methods for the case? Some program to do so? I am some experience of FEM but to visualise so complex case is challenging. Some script to visualise the falling house? There is only 100 millimeters support at the corners of the house for the cavity plates.

### Simulation #1: 2D visualisation about falling plate from pillars

Two pillars on which the plate is. The movement down (90 mm) and laterally (120 mm) is known. The margin is 100 mm on which the plate is on both sides. Also, it is known that the pillars are 3-5 degrees skewed to one side.
Any example Matlab codes for visualising this?

The more challenging part is to put the house to rest on the mud.

### Other simulations

Comment: So reference something just about everyone has heard of: the Leaning tower of Pisa...

Comment: Novices like pictures and videos these days... So generate a few frames as best you can and leave it at that.

Comment: @abel there is laser data of the falling house and moving house done by the city at the floor level measurements. Also tachymetry data of the foundations. However, I need to visualise to amateurs what falling and moving house can mean in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple drawing is all that "amateurs" need.  "The house has moved this much in these directions and is in imminent danger of collapse."

Comment: Can you please propose some visualisation examples? I understand but the court has to be convinced.

Comment: A drawing of the house and arrows